# Template contains errors.: Invalid template resource property 'Fn::ImportValue'

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I have A template that creates IAM roles In cloud Formation YAML. I need service Anr in next template, But I am getting this error.

## Template contains errors.: Invalid template resource property 'Fn::ImportValue'

IAMStack

`Resources:
  CodeDeployTrustRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Sid: '1'
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - codedeploy.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
            - codedeploy.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
  CodeDeployRolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: CodeDeployPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Resource:
          - "*"
          Action:
          - ec2:Describe*
        - Effect: Allow
          Resource:
          - "*"
          Action:
          - autoscaling:CompleteLifecycleAction
          - autoscaling:DeleteLifecycleHook
          - autoscaling:DescribeLifecycleHooks
          - autoscaling:DescribeAutoScalingGroups
          - autoscaling:PutLifecycleHook
          - autoscaling:RecordLifecycleActionHeartbeat
      Roles:
      - Ref: CodeDeployTrustRole
  InstanceRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - ec2.amazonaws.com
          Action:
          - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"
  InstanceRolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: InstanceRole
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - autoscaling:Describe*
          - autoscaling:EnterStandby
          - autoscaling:ExitStandby
          - cloudformation:Describe*
          - cloudformation:GetTemplate
          - s3:Get*
          Resource: "*"
      Roles:
      - Ref: InstanceRole
  InstanceRoleInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
      - Ref: InstanceRole
Outputs:
  CodeDeployServiceRoleARN:
    Value:
      Fn::GetAtt:
      - CodeDeployTrustRole
      - Arn`

==================================================================================
CodeDeploystack

`---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: This template will create an s3bucket
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead
      BucketName: CodeDeploy
  CodeDeployApplication:
   Type: 'AWS::CodeDeploy::Application'
   Properties:
    ComputePlatform: ec2
  DeploymentGroup: 
   Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
   Properties: 
    ApplicationName: 
      !Ref CodeDeployApplication
    Deployment: 
      Description: First time
      IgnoreApplicationStopFailures: true
      Revision:
        RevisionType: S3
        S3Location: 
          Bucket: 
            Ref: S3Bucket
  ServiceRoleArn: 
    'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${IAMStack}-CodeDeployServiceRoleARN'
Outputs:
  S3BucketName:
    Value:
      Ref: S3Bucket
    Description: Name of S3 bucket`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried rewriting your second template with the import function. Can you try something like this:

`AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: This template will create an s3bucket
Resources:
  S3Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties:
      AccessControl: PublicRead 
      BucketName: CodeDeploy
  CodeDeployApplication:
    Type: "AWS::CodeDeploy::Application"
    Properties:
      ComputePlatform: ec2
  DeploymentGroup:
    Type: AWS::CodeDeploy::DeploymentGroup
    Properties:
        ApplicationName: !Ref CodeDeployApplication
        Deployment:
          Description: First time
          IgnoreApplicationStopFailures: true
          Revision:
            RevisionType: S3
            S3Location: !Ref S3Bucket
        ServiceRoleArn:
          Fn::ImportValue:
            Fn::Sub "${IAMStack}-CodeDeployServiceRoleARN"
Outputs:
  S3BucketName:
    Value: !Ref S3Bucket
    Description: Name of S3 bucket`

I think some quotes may be off in your version.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, I just change the region